# Magento2 PayPal Recaptcha module not working for multi website

Tags: magento-2.1.3, multi-website, recaptcha, magento2.2.8

Due to the recent carding activity of PayPal Payflow Pro, I'm working on getting the magento recommended PayPal Recaptcha module installed and configured per this article (https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025515991-PayPal-Payflow-Pro-active-carding-activity).

I've got it installed and configured. However, I can only get the captcha to display when I have the keys placed at the default config scope. This magento instance is a multi website setup with separate domains. When I place the domain specific keys in the specific website scopes, the captcha goes away and won't display.

I'm using reCaptcha V2. I've tested this on an instance of Magento 2.2.8 and Magento 2.1.3 with the same results. I've also had the same results using the test reCaptcha V2 keys that Google provides. Has anyone had this issue on a multi store setup?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Don't use website specific credentials and just create reCAPTCHA v2 keys that work for any domain you want them placed on. Set them for the default configuration scope and this should work like a charm. I'm still unsure why the website specific keys would not work. If anyone has any input on that I'd still love to hear it.